# Vector initialization in a structure

Tags: c++, vector

I have introduced a new vector in a pre-existing structure St, which is like this `std::vector<X>   xInfo;` X is another newly defined structure with members of primitive data types. Now there is a pre-existing code like `memset(&s, 0, sizeof(St));` where s is an instance of St. What type of problem it will cause due to the addition of the vector`xInfo` into `St`?

How to overcome the issues so that I can keep the new vector inside the structure?

EDIT : Below is a sample code of for the situation

> ```
> // Below section is new code.
>
> typedef struct
> {
>     char    m11;
>     int     m12;
>     char    m13[50];
> }X;
> ```

```
// Below section is existing code.

typedef struct{
    char             m1[10];
    int              m2;
    long             m3;
    double           m4;
```

> ```
>     vector<X>        xInfo;   /* this line is newly added code */
> ```

```
}St;

void fun(const char* a1, int a2, long m3, double m4)
{
    St    s;

    memset(&s, 0, sizeof(St));

    if(NULL != a1 && 0 != a1[0])
        strncpy(m1, a1, 9);

    m2 = a2;
    m3 = a3;
    m4 = a4;

    ........
    ........
}
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to use memset() for class objects, especially STL items like std::vector (where you do not know how it is built).  If you provide code, we might offer more useful feedback.  I would think the memset() can be used on any POD item, but typically, assignment is easier.  Please review [MCVE].

Comment: *Now there is a pre-existing code like memset(&s, 0, sizeof(St))* -- Well, to put it plainly, it's time for you to change the `memset` code, or else you'll be in for a lot of grief.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN I have added code example in the EDIT section, please suggest a solution to retain the existing behavior with the new code. Is there any other solution apart from adding a constructor of `St`?

Answer (score 2):

This will result in undefined behavior.

Translation: most likely a crash.

Answer (score 1):

memset() will certainly confuse your run time.

```
St    s;
memset(&s, 0, sizeof(St));
```

Because s contains a std::vector, your vector will be stomped on by this memset(), and not in the way you want it.

As I said in my comment above, you do *not* know how the std::vector<> is built.  As an example, on Ubuntu 15.10, with g++ 5.2.1, a std::vector<> is only 24 bytes, regardless of how many elements.  Here is a partial output from a small program of mine:

```
typedef std::vector< UI224 >  VecUI224;
sizeof(VecUI224)                : 24

VecUI224 vui224; 
sizeof(vui224)  : 24    vui224.size() = 000000    vui224.capacity() : 00000
sizeof(vui224)  : 24    vui224.size() = 000001    vui224.capacity() : 00001
sizeof(vui224)  : 24    vui224.size() = 100       vui224.capacity() : 128
sizeof(vui224)  : 24    vui224.size() = 200       vui224.capacity() : 256
// ...
sizeof(vui224)  : 24    vui224.size() = 900       vui224.capacity() : 1024
sizeof(vui224)  : 24    vui224.size() = 1000      vui224.capacity() : 1024
```

IMHO (I have not yet inspected the vector template code) the 24 bytes contains some pointers and overhead. The inferred pointers point into heap, and none of the data will be in the vector object.  Stomping with memset() will merely corrupt the vector, the data of X is not there

Your existing memset() would simply wipe out these vector pointer(s) and overhead, but not the data.  Probably resulting in a crash.

The proper way to initialize a struct (or class) is to create a constructor and assign values via the initializer list appropriately.

Example 1 is C style, and you really need to move to C++:

```
typedef struct{
   char             m1[10];
   int              m2;
   long             m3;
   double           m4;
   vector<X>        xInfo;   /* this line is newly added code */
}St;
```

A possible C++ approach: Create the ctor, add an initialization list.

```
struct St_t    // I use suffix '_t' to indicate a type
{
   St_t (void) :  // ctor
      // m1[10]  see body of ctor
      m2 (0),
      m3 (0),
      m4 (0)
      // xInfo - see default ctor of X_t below
   {
       // it is ok to consider this, but raises the wtf factor
       ::memset(m1, 0, 10); // for the single pod
   }
   char             m1[10];
   int              m2;
   long             m3;
   double           m4;

   vector<X_t>        xInfo;   /* this line is newly added code */
};
```

---

The for xInfo, the C++ approach might be something like the following:

```
struct  X_t
{
   X_t(void) :    // type X_t default dtor
       m11(0), 
       m12(0) 
       // m13 
   {
      // I would fill m13 with
      for (int i=0;i<50; ++i)
         m13[i] = 0;
   }
   char    m11;
   int     m12;
   char    m13[50];
};
```

All data fields initialized (here to 0) during ctor.
Any time you instantiate another instance, these ctor's ensure the data is initialized.

---

> ...is there any other solution...?

Software is infinitely flexible, but ctor's are the simplest and most self documenting approach.

---

> How to overcome the issues so that I can keep the new vector inside
>   the structure?

I see no issue with keeping the vector inside of the old struct.  The ctor is the most appropriate approach.

Comment: Thanks @DOUGLAS, I have implemented with the same approach.